# How to manipulate SQL IN Operator to return all values as a result

Tags: java, sql, select, in-operator

I am working on a Java code whose sole purpose is to display all data from the database table.

The query for fetching the table-data, from the database, is written in the jar.

The table structure is kind of like:

```
Column1  Column2  City 
Dummy    Dummy    abc
Dummy    Dummy    xyz
Dummy    Dummy    pqr
Dummy    Dummy    ALL
```

Previously, the sql command in the jar looked like this:

```
  select * from table;
```

But now in the newer version of jar, the query is like:

```
select * 
from table 
where city In ( variable ,'All');
```

The variable is filled at runtime and is a string variable.

Now the problem is, I don't have any control on the jar and I can't change anything in it.

And my goal remains same to display everything in the table.**

I tried putting `' '` (blank) in the command, but it returns only the rows with city as ALL.

So is there any way I can get all rows as a result using in operator, OR should I go back to previous jar having the simple select query.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can pass dynamic or run-time value in query.

```
DECLARE @ParameterDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX) 
 SET @ParameterDefinition = '@P_Filter NVARCHAR(MAX)';

DECLARE @SQL  NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Filter  NVARCHAR(MAX) = '' //set here filter value

SET  @SQL = 'select * from table where city In (@P_Filter);'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, @ParameterDefinition,
@P_Filter = @Filter
```

OR 
Pass the value using `STRING_SPLIT Function`

```
select * from table where city In (STRING_SPLIT([FILTER_VALUE]));
```

For more details visit this link [Click me](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-string-functions/sql-server-string_split-function/)

Comment: This is a database specific answer to a question that didn't state the database product being used.

Answer (score 0):

use `case` statement or `mysql` `if` function to check if your `variable` is empty

```
select * from table where city In (if(length(variable) > 0, city , ''), 'All');
```